# What is the difference between options below to convert strings in a list to integer?

Tags: string, list, integer, typeconverter

Why I can not convert the string in the list to integer with code 1 although I can with code 2?

Code1

```
x=input("Enter the notes with space after each element").split()
for i in x:
  i=int(i)
print(x)
```

Code 2

```
x=input("Enter the notes with space after each element").split()
for i in range(0,len(x)):
   x[i]=int(x[i])
print(x)
```

I tried code 1 but i does not work.

```
Code1
```

x=input("Enter the notes with space after each element").split()
for i in x:
i=int(i)
print(x)

Comment: In code1, your values in x are not changed, while in code2 they are changed

Comment: Thanks, I understand but I think I do not know the logic. How the elements change in list in the case of second code although it does not change for first code=